# add "text" automatically after each line in a list

Tags: c#

I need a solution for this example:
I have a two Richtextbox for example & I want to add something automatically after each line
for example i want to add " . " (dot) after each line

### & if i enter this in the richtextbox1:

you are

### funny

### automatically i see this in the richtextbox2:

you are.

### funny.

I need a solution for this
& if someone have a solution but with other lists (listview listbox (textbox multiline)...)
it's ok too.

Comment: You need to add a minimum code sample to show an attempt. Your question is not acceptable for stackoverflow.

Comment: If you need a solution I suggest you open your text book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you are using Windows Forms, in which case you can implement this in the `TextChanged` event

Example:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
}
```

But, that is not what you want to do... I would manipulate the string using `.Split()`

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] splitNewlines = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
    string newText = "";
    foreach (string s in splitNewlines)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            newText += s + "." + "\n";
        else
            newText += "\n";
    }
    richTextBox2.Text = newText;
}
```

That will split the original string, add a period and a newline, and do this for every newline in the original text. Picture:

[image: working program]

Answer (score -1):

I assume u are adding this on some event. For example a button click, transfering some text from a textBox to your richtextbox.

U could try this:

```
this.richTextBox1.AppendText(textBox1.Text + "." + "\n");
```

This will add a dot at the end of the text, that it was in the textbox.